# Violating the triangle inequality

Tags: real-analysis

I am looking for a set $X$ and distance metric $d(x,y)$ which has

- $d(x,x)=0$ for all $x$
- (Positive) $d(x,y)>0$ for all $x \ne y$
- (Symmetric) $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$ for all $x,y$

But *not*

- (Triangle inequality) For all $(x,y,z) \in X, d(x,z)  \leq d(x,y) + d(y,z)$.

I tried some small discrete sets with simple distance rules but no luck so far.

Comment: This may be overkill, but I do believe the $L^p$ spaces for $0 < p < 1$ do not have the triangle inequality. Here, the metric is induced by the usual norm on this space. That is, $d(f, g) = ||f - g||_p$.

Comment: If you really mean **strict** inequality then this can be seen from just regular Euclidean distance by taking three points in a line (with $y$ being between $x$ and $z$).

Comment: @ErickWong I don't understand. Euclidean distances over $(1,10, 50)$ doesn't violate the triangle inequality, does it?

Comment: @Hatshepsut It depends on whether you made a typo.  The triangle inequality is indeed true for those distances, but what you wrote down is not the triangle inequality ($<$ vs $\le$).  That can also be fairly called a “triangle” inequality since it can detect whether three points form a triangle (rather than lying in a line).

Comment: @ErickWong Ah, yes that was a typo, fixed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may take $X =\{a,b,c\}$ with

$$d(a,b)=3, d(b,c)=1, d(c,a)=1$$

and complete the remaining distances by $d(x,x)=0$ and  $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$. This satisfies your properties, but

$$d(a,b) > d(a,c) + d(c,b)$$

Answer (score 8):

By definition, a [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Definition) **will** satisfy the triangle inequality. What you are looking for is a *semimetric*.

It is easy to see that, for $p\in(0,1)$ the function $d\colon\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n \to [0,\infty)$ defined as
$$
d(x,y) = \lVert x-y\rVert_p =  \left( \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i-y_i|^p \right)^{1/p}
$$
is indeed a semimetric. (The triangle inequality is only satisfied for $p\geq 1$, for which $\lVert \cdot \rVert_p$ is a bona fide norm.)

Comment: I always thought a semimetric was one where $d(x,y)=0$ did not imply $x=y$. This way, a seminorm induces a semimetric.

Comment: It *would* make sense, I agree, @TheoreticalEconomist. (Unfortunately, it does not...)

Comment: Now I know why I thought this: I actually learned it from a textbook. Which is a little odd, since the aforementioned book was otherwise pretty forthcoming when their notation / terminology is non-standard. TIL.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\ X\ :=\ \mathbb R\ $ be the set of all reals. Define:

$$ \forall_{k\ n\in\mathbb Z}\quad \delta(k\ n)\ :=\ (k-n)^2 $$

Your axioms are satisfied for $\ \delta,\ $ while

$$ \delta(k\ m)+\delta(m\ n)\ <\ \delta(k\ n) $$

whenever $\ k<m<n\ $ (for $\ k\ m\ n\in\mathbb R$).

> **REMARK**   Draw the three square of the above inequality ($(k-n)^2,\ $ etc.) and you'll clearly see that indeed the inequality holds.